# Asus P10S-C/4L won't get past Q Code 62 with Intel E3-1220 v6 and 8GB of DDR4 2400 ecc

Tags: boot, uefi

Upon power up, the Asus logo appears on screen and the Q Codes change as it moves through the boot procedure until 62 is reached where it gets stuck and stays until I reset or power off. I have sent an email to Asus but they have not replied and I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction? I have looked up the Q Code in the manual and it means SB run time init which I have no clue to what it is about.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Оn the motherboard (Asus P10S-C/4L) there is a sticker with the BIOS version
For example, I have 0506 BIOS version. But Intel Xeon E3-1220 V6 compatible with 3104 BIOS version. I have same problem - q code 62.

1. Use CPU support table
   https://www.asus.com/Commercial-Servers-Workstations/P10S-C-4L/HelpDesk_CPU/
2. Install the processor that is compatible for your BIOS version.
   For example, I use Celeron G3900
3. Then Download Latest BIOS and update CPU MicroCode with ezFlash tool.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Q Code 62 usually has to do with GPU issues.  Please ensure the following:

- GPU is seated correctly (you may want to pull the card and re-seat it)
- Power cables for the GPU from the power supply are plugged in fully
- If you can get to your BIOS, look in there and make sure the 3.3, 5, and 12v readouts are correct (you want all of the values to be fairly close to the stated numbers).